# How to improve performance of SQL query with parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, parameters, where-clause

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

I have a problems with executing SQL statements like this

```
DECLARE @Param1 BIT
SET @Param1 = 1

SELECT 
    t1.Col1,
    t1.Col2
FROM
    Table1 t1
WHERE
    @Param1=0 OR
    (t1.Col2 in 
        (SELECT  t2.Col4
            FROM 
                Table2 t2
            WHERE 
                t2.Col1 = t1.Col1 AND 
                t2.Col2 = 'AAA' AND 
                t2.t3 <> 0)
    )
```

This query executes very long time.

But if I replace `@Param1` with `1`, than query execution time is ~2 seconds.

Any information how to resolve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the XML version of the actual execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the explanation seems simple enough. For your current condition, since `@Param1=0` is false (you set the parameter to 1 previously), it needs to evaluate your second condition, wich has a subquery and might take a long time. If you change your first filter to `@Param1=1`, then you are saying that it is true and there is no need to evaluate your second filter, hence making your query faster.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing the optimiser with your OR statement.  If you remove it, you should find it generates two different execution plans for the SELECT statement - one with a filter, and the other without:

```
DECLARE @Param1 BIT
SET @Param1 = 1

if @Param1=0
begin
    SELECT 
        t1.Col1,
        t1.Col2
    FROM
        Table1 t1
end
else
begin
    SELECT 
        t1.Col1,
        t1.Col2
    FROM
        Table1 t1
    WHERE
        (t1.Col2 in 
            (SELECT  t2.Col4
                FROM 
                    Table2 t2
                WHERE 
                    t2.Col1 = t1.Col1 AND 
                    t2.Col2 = 'AAA' AND 
                    t2.t3 <> 0)
        )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly referred to as the N+1 problem. 
You're doing a select in table 1 and for each record you find you will go look for something in table 2.
By setting your @Param1 to an value which will never be found in your select the sql engine will skip the subquery.
To avoid this behavior you could use a JOIN statement to join both tables together and afterwards filter the results with a where statement. The join statement will be a bit slower then a single subquery because you are matching 2 tables to eachother but because you only need to do the join once(vs N times) you'll gain a serious performance boost.

Example code :

```
DECLARE @Param1 BIT
SET @Param1 = 1

SELECT t1.Col1,t1.Col2
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
WHERE @Param1=0 
OR t2.Col2 = 'AAA' 
AND t2.t3 <> 0
```